# Android 11 Storage Access Framework copy multiple files (Images/videos) to external storage

Tags: android, storage

I want to copy files from Android/media to the Pictures, is there a way to do it without asking every time to copy a file? I already have the Uris I need to copy but everything I tried doesn't worked,

For copying images I use this code:

```
public void fileToPictures(Context context, String filename, Bitmap image) {
    try {
        Bitmap bm = image;
        File directory = null;
        directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File file = new File(directory, filename + ".png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.getFD().sync();
        outputStream.close();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {
            file.getAbsolutePath()
        }, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sticker saved in pictures as:   " + filename + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sticker couldn't be saved. Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use full paths for your folders.

Comment: Further you can just copy files without asking even once.

Comment: But how, I don't get it, for images it was simple but I can not get it work for videos...

Comment: I dont see you copy a file. And i also dont see that something is asked. I dont see you using an uri. I dont see you using SAF.

Comment: Yeah you're right I tried to copy but then I recycled just old code. Its working now with ContentResolver.